# Delete vacuum/empty line in text.txt with PHP

Tags: php, line, emptydatatext

I try to delete the vacuum line. 
My script, search a line, delete her, but it's remains a vacuum line.

```
hello
dude
world
```

I did this script :

```
$chaine="dude"; 
$file=$filename; 
$texte = file_get_contents($file); 
$texte = str_replace($chaine ,'',$texte); 
$texte = preg_replace('/\s+/s', "\n", $texte);

try
    {

        if(!$fd = fopen($filename, "w")){
            throw new Exception("Erreur ouverture du fichier");
        }
    else
    {   
        fwrite($fd, $texte); 

        /*On ferme le fichier*/
        fclose($fd);    
    }

    }

    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error de parametre fichier introuvable (File: ".$e->getFile().", line ".
        $e->getLine()."): ".$e->getMessage();
        echo "\n";
    }
```

And I have

```
hello
world
```

But if I delete the first one : hello, I have a vacuum line :

```
(vacuum line)
world
```

How can I fix the problem ?

I try trim, str_replace but it's doesn't work...

Comment: `$texte = preg_replace('/^'.preg_quote($chaine, '/').'[\r\n]+/', '', $texte);`

Comment: Works only ofr the first line. if $chaine = world, it's doesn't work

Comment: Change `[\r\n]+` to `(?:[\r\n]+|$)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
$texte = str_replace($chaine ,'',$texte); 
$texte = preg_replace('/\s+/s', "\n", $texte);
```

with this:

```
$texte = preg_replace('#' . $chaine . '\s*#', "\r", $texte);
```

I don't know how your linebreaks look like, but try with "\r", "\n" or "\r\n" as the replacement string.

Comment: works perfectly ! Thx ! :) what's the use of ? '#' in the line ?

Comment: They're regex delimiters. You need to have them at the beginning and the end of your regex string; it could be any unusual character, like `%`, `#`, `¤`, `~`, `^` or `/`.